CPU limits exceeded LOGS
Need help/advice. I have received an error with my custom solution to sent mass emails.
Apex is super simple just sending list of emails(out of loop). When sending 99 emails to 99 different contacts i am reaching CPU limits.
I have downloaded logs and what i saw scared me 153 000 lines. When my Apex code is completed(i am guessing that because my debugs are no longer displayed), i reach Maximum CPU time: 361 out of 10000.
When i scroll down to line 153149 just before i see an error final LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS:
 Number of SOQL queries: 89 out of 100 ******* CLOSE TO LIMIT
  Number of query rows: 89 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 87 out of 150 ******* CLOSE TO LIMIT
  Number of Publish Immediate DML: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 87 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 21407 out of 10000 ******* CLOSE TO LIMIT
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 1 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

When im randomly scrolling through log  i can see that flows, validation rules, process builder are being called. But only for 99 emails reaching that high limit.
If you can advice me what to do. I know and i'm planning to splice those email in batches but still amount of CPU used is insane.
Thanks in advance
LWC component:
JS

import {LightningElement, track} from 'lwc';
import getContactsByEmailAddress from '@salesforce/apex/OPERATIONS_MassMailingController.getContactsByEmailAddresses';
import getMassEmailEmailTemplates from '@salesforce/apex/OPERATIONS_MassMailingController.getMassEmailsEmailTemplates';
import sendSingleEmailMethodSeparately from '@salesforce/apex/OPERATIONS_SendEmailController.sendSingleEmailMethodSeparately';
import {ShowToastEvent} from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";
import {CloseActionScreenEvent} from "lightning/actions";

const columns = [
    { label: 'Email Address', fieldName: 'emailAddress', type: 'email' },
    { label: 'Contact', fieldName: 'contactURL', type: 'url', typeAttributes: {label:'Contact Link'} }
];

export default class MassMailing extends LightningElement {

    columns = columns;
    data = [];
    displayFirstComponent = true;
    displaySecondComponent = false;
    displaySpinner = false;
    emailTemplatesFetched = false;
    emailTemplateDisabled = true;
    emailAddresses = '';
    passedEmailAddresses = [];
    emailTemplateValue;
    bodyValue;
    showModal = false;
    emailTemplatesArray = [];
    @track emailTemplateOptions = [];
    casePicked;
    sendEmailDisabled = false;
    countOfPastedEmailAddresses = 0;
    countOfMappedEmailAddresses = 0;
    uniqueContacts = new Set();
    countOfUniqueContacts = 0;
    contactIds = [];
    subjectValue;
    isCasePicked = false;
    duplicates = new Set();
    duplicatesValues = [];
    emailSent;
    displayInfo = {
        primaryField: 'CaseNumber',
        additionalFields: ['Subject'],
    };
    matchingInfo = {
        primaryField: { fieldPath: 'CaseNumber' },
        additionalFields: [{ fieldPath: 'Subject' }],
    };


    connectedCallback() {
        this.getEmailTemplates();
    }

    get isSendEmailDisabled(){
        return !(this.displaySecondComponent && this.isCasePicked && !this.emailTemplateDisabled)
    }

    matchContacts(){
        this.displaySecondComponent = false;
        this.displaySpinner = true;
        this.uniqueContacts.clear();
        this.duplicatesValues = [];
        this.contactIds = [];
        this.duplicates.clear();
        this.prepareEmailAddresses();
        getContactsByEmailAddress({emailAddresses: this.passedEmailAddresses}).then((result) => {
                this.displaySpinner = false;
                this.displaySecondComponent = true;
                if (result.length > 0){
                    this.data = result;
                    this.countOfMappedEmailAddresses = result.length;
                    result.forEach(contact => {
                        if (this.uniqueContacts.has(contact.emailAddress)){
                            this.duplicates.add(contact.emailAddress);
                        }
                        this.uniqueContacts.add(contact.emailAddress);
                        this.contactIds.push(contact.id);
                    });
                    this.duplicates.forEach(value => {
                        this.duplicatesValues.push(value);
                    })
                    this.countOfUniqueContacts = this.uniqueContacts.size;
                }
            }
        ).catch(error => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    }

    getEmailTemplates(){
        getMassEmailEmailTemplates().then((result) =>{
            if(result.length > 0){
                this.emailTemplatesArray = result;
                result.forEach( emailTemplate =>{
                    this.emailTemplateOptions.push({label: emailTemplate.Name, value: emailTemplate.Id});
                })
                this.emailTemplatesFetched = true;
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    }

    prepareEmailAddresses(){
        if (this.emailAddresses.endsWith(';')){
            this.emailAddresses = this.emailAddresses.substring(0, this.emailAddresses.length - 1);
        }
        this.passedEmailAddresses = this.emailAddresses.split(';');
        this.countOfPastedEmailAddresses = this.passedEmailAddresses.length;
    }

    sendEmail(){
        this.sendEmailDisabled = true;
        const recordInput = {body: this.bodyValue, toAddresses: this.contactIds, Subject: this.subjectValue, whatId: this.casePicked, ccAddresses: []}
        sendSingleEmailMethodSeparately(recordInput)
            .then( (data) => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: "Success",
                        message: "You have successfully sent all emails. Now you can close the window.",
                        variant: "success",
                    }),
                );
            }).catch( error => {
            this.sendEmailDisabled = false;
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: "Error sending email",
                    message: error.body.message,
                    variant: "error",
                }),
            );
        })
    }

    handleCasePick(event){
        this.casePicked = event.detail.recordId;
        this.isCasePicked = (event.detail.recordId !== null);
    }


    handleEmailTemplateChange(event){
        this.emailTemplateValue = event.detail.value;
        this.selectedEmail = this.emailTemplatesArray.find((element) => element.Id === event.detail.value);
        this.bodyValue = this.selectedEmail.HtmlValue;
        this.subjectValue = this.selectedEmail.Subject;
        this.emailTemplateDisabled = false;
    }

    handleBodyChange(event){
        this.bodyValue = event.target.value;
    }

    populateEmailAddresses(event){
        this.emailAddresses = event.detail.value;
    }

    subjectChange(event){
        this.subjectValue = event.target.value;
    }

    previewBody(){
        this.showModal = true;
    }

    closeModal(){
        this.showModal = false;
    }
}

HTML
<template>
    <template lwc:if={displayFirstComponent}>
            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-theme_default" style="padding: 1em">
                <div class="slds-col slds-large-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning-textarea class="slds-p-top_small" onchange={populateEmailAddresses} name="emailAddresses" label="Paste semi-colon delimited email addresses" placeholder="paste email addresses here..."></lightning-textarea>
                    Pasted Email Addresses: <b>{countOfPastedEmailAddresses}</b><br>
                    Mapped Contacts: <b>{countOfMappedEmailAddresses}</b><br>
                    Unique Contacts: <b>{countOfUniqueContacts}</b><br>
                    Duplicate Email Addresses: {duplicatesValues}
                    <lightning-record-picker
                            label="Case"
                            placeholder="Search Cases..."
                            object-api-name="Case"
                            display-info={displayInfo}
                            matching-info={matchingInfo}
                            onchange={handleCasePick}
                    ></lightning-record-picker>
                    <template lwc:if={emailTemplatesFetched}>
                        <lightning-combobox
                                label="Mass Email Templates"
                                value={value}
                                placeholder="Select Email Template"
                                options={emailTemplateOptions}
                                onchange={handleEmailTemplateChange} >
                        </lightning-combobox>
                    </template>
                    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Match Contacts" title="Primary action" onclick={matchContacts} class="slds-m-left_x-small slds-float_right padding-top"></lightning-button>
                    <lightning-button variant="brand" disabled={isSendEmailDisabled} label="Preview Email" title="Primary action" onclick={previewBody} class="slds-m-left_x-small slds-float_right padding-top"></lightning-button>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col slds-large-size_1-of-2">
                    <template lwc:if={displaySpinner}>
                        <div class="exampleHolder">
                            <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading" size="large" variant="brand"></lightning-spinner>
                        </div>
                    </template>
                    <template lwc:if={displaySecondComponent}>
                        <div class="data-table-height">
                            <lightning-datatable
                                    key-field="id"
                                    data={data}
                                    show-row-number-column
                                    hide-checkbox-column
                                    columns={columns}>
                            </lightning-datatable>
                        </div>
                    </template>
                </div>

            </div>
    </template>
    <!-- modal start -->
    <template lwc:if={showModal}>
        <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
            <div class="slds-modal__container" style="max-width: 50rem">
                <header class="slds-modal__header">
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse" title="Close" onclick={closeModal}>
                        <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close"
                                        alternative-text="close"
                                        variant="inverse"
                                        size="small" ></lightning-icon>
                        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
                    </button>
                    <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">Email Preview</h2>
                </header>

                <!-- modal body start -->
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
                    <lightning-input type="text" label="From" placeholder="" disabled></lightning-input>
                    <lightning-input type="text" label="Subject" onchange={subjectChange} value={subjectValue}></lightning-input>
                    <lightning-input-rich-text
                            value={bodyValue}
                            onchange={handleBodyChange}>
                    </lightning-input-rich-text>
                </div>

                <!-- modal footer start-->
                <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                    <lightning-button label="Close" title="Primary action" onclick={closeModal} class="slds-m-left_x-small slds-float_right padding-top"></lightning-button>
                    <lightning-button variant="brand" disabled={sendEmailDisabled} label="Send Emails" title="Primary action" onclick={sendEmail} class="slds-m-left_x-small slds-float_right padding-top"></lightning-button>
                </footer>

            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
    </template>
    <!-- modal end -->
</template>

Apex class
@AuraEnabled
    public static String sendSingleEmailMethodSeparately(String body, List<String> toAddresses, String Subject, String whatId, List<String> ccAddresses){
        List<OrgWideEmailAddress> owea = removed due to compliance

        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> listOfEmails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        for (String recipient: toAddresses){
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mymail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            if ( owea.size() > 0 ) {
                mymail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owea.get(0).Id);
            }


            body = body.replaceAll('<p><br></p>','<br />\n');
            body = body.replaceAll('<p>&nbsp;</p>','');
            body = body.replaceAll('</p><p>','</br />\n');
            body = body.replaceAll('<p>','');
            body = body.replaceAll('</p>','<br />\n');
            if (!body.contains('<head>')){
                body = '<html>\n' +
                        '<head>\n' +
                        '<title></title>\n' +
                        '</head>\n' +
                        '<body aria-readonly="false" style="font-family: Verdana,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; height: auto; min-height: auto;">' + body;
            }

            String bodyWithoutFooter = body.substringBefore('Best regards');
            body = bodyWithoutFooter


            mymail.setTargetObjectId(recipient);
            mymail.setSubject(Subject);
            mymail.setHtmlBody(body);
            mymail.setPlainTextBody(body);
            mymail.setWhatId(whatId);
            mymail.setCcAddresses(ccAddresses);
            mymail.setTreatBodiesAsTemplate(true);
            listOfEmails.add(mymail);
        }
        List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> results = Messaging.sendEmail(listOfEmails);
        return results.toString();
    }


Please add your Apex code to your question, even if you think it's trivial. And explain where (according to the logs) Flows etc. are called resp. validation rules passed. There is more going awry here than reaching a CPU limit.

Added Apex and LWC

You could remove the LWC code, which has no relevance here. True, the code sending the emails is sound. Of more interest is the code e.g. in a trigger or Flow on EmailMessage. I suspect it to be not properly bulkified. If you don't need EmailMessage records, add mymail.setSaveAsActivity(false); to your Apex. This is likely to significantly reduce your Limits usage.

Hopefully you are aware of these General Email Limits - read this carefully to see if you will be within the 5,000 email limit or not.
The logic your code executes - DML operations - can trigger logic in the org (triggers, process flows etc) added by others. Breaking your emailing up into smaller batches has a good chance of working-around the problem. But ideally you would discuss with the authors what their logic is for to confirm that it is appropriate that it runs for your change.

I am aware of that limit and it's fine. Those people are no longer in company. But i need kind of confirmation that if debug log says after all my system.debug that cpu used in that apex operation is 361 out of 10000. Then the problem is no in apex but all other validation rules, flows etc.
